# How can I pass in rendered HTML to a vue property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-material

I'm using `vue-material` and I have:

```
  <md-dialog-confirm
    :md-active="true"
    md-title="Make an Outboud Call"
    md-confirm-text="Agree"
    md-cancel-text="Disagree"
    md-content="some <p>HTML</p> here"
    @md-cancel="$emit('closeModal')"
    @md-confirm="$emit('accept')"
  >
```

For `md-content`, I can pass HTML but want it to be rendered via the Vue.js template engine so I can use my `{{template interpolation }}` as needed.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a dynamically generated HTML. If it is just a simple case, you could even do it inline with a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
  <md-dialog-confirm
    :md-active="true"
    md-title="Make an Outboud Call"
    md-confirm-text="Agree"
    md-cancel-text="Disagree"
    :md-content="`some text with the value <b>${yourVariable}</b> here`"
    @md-cancel="$emit('closeModal')"
    @md-confirm="$emit('accept')"
  >
```

Note the `:` in front of `md-content` which is the shorthand for [`v-bind`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html).